# NSString memory leak on componentsJoinedByString

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsstring

In a non-ARC project I wrote this snippet :

```
- (NSString *)formattedName
{
    NSCharacterSet *charset = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
    NSArray *components     = [self.name componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charset];
    NSString *str1          = [components componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
    NSString *str2          = [str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<n>" withString:@""];
    return str2;
}
```

It's decomposed because I want to track a memory leak Instruments showed me.
My str1 variable leaked with componentsJoinedByString. I really don't know why. Is it an iOS system leak (iOS 7.1) ?

Comment: it may be the iOS issue, if you are not allocating the memory then you shouldn't be worry about release.

Comment: Yes I thought so but a leak on a old method like this seemed weird to me. Thx anyway ;)

Comment: What makes you think it is leaking?

Comment: @JeremyP : Instruments told me

Comment: Have you got an autorelease pool?

Answer (score 0):

As you're not using ARC have you thought about "deconstructing it" even further?

Instead of using literals (`@"<n>"` for example) I would create those NSString instances as their own statements, and be sure to release them properly ... see if you're still leaking then?